# Android GridView: Animation for grids when add or remove programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

How to define an animation for GridView grids in Andorid?

For example when I add or remove an item, GridView will automatically animate the action(eg fadeIn/fadeOut) and re-order the items.

Comment: @pskink
Could you introduce me a live example or explain much more?

Comment: http://www.google.com/m?q=layoutanimationcontroller+example&client=ms-opera-mini-android&channel=new

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the [ListViewAnimations](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations) library which also works with `GridView`s.